# Find integer $n$ for which $n$ divide $2ⁿ+1$

Tags: logic, integers

Find integer $n$ for which $n$ divide $2^n +1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $n$ is any integer, then $n=1$ will do.

Comment: $0$ divides $0$ as well (*under most reasonable definitions*), so if you're going to include these edge cases $n=0$ ought to be mentioned as well.